# Safari blocking cookies in apple devices

Tags: ios, reactjs, cookies, backend

I have such a problem that Safari blocks cookies, or does not record them at all, I'll start from the beginning. There is a backend and a frontend, when logging in, a request occurs and there we save cookies in the request header, the token itself is stored in redux, for any actions and requests where we need access with a token, an interceptor is used. In the interceptor, we refresh the token, in the desktop version and android, everything works fine, but on Apple devices, this same refresh does not occur, it says that the token is supposedly expired, and there are no cookies in the request headers at all. What could be the reason? I have an assumption that this is possible because of the api domain and the main domain, because the api domain looks like: "api.xxx.xxx.xxx.", and the main domain looks like: "xxx-xxx.xxx". What could be the reason?

Answer (score 0):

Try preferences->privacy->turn off 'prevent cross-site tracking'.
After the operation, you will find the browser could save cookie.

Comment: So the fact is that it should be only on the site, the user will not include it for one site. And I also forgot to mention that on another site, with the same cookie logic, everything works great, but there is the domain api.xxx.com api, the domain of the site xxx.com